# How to properly add multiple elements event in jQuery custom plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write my first jquery plugin and I'm having some difficulties trying to implement functions, events and triggers.

Here is the scenario in which I'm working.

1. I've multiple input box with same class eg. "numberTextBox"
2. Apply plugin directly to these classes eg. "$(".numberTextBox").inputNumericTextBox();".
3. I can also give settings in it.
4. Now plugin should allow only numeric value based on setting either given on default.
5. what I had in my mind is to properly convert and verify any given value. I want to use both onkeypress and onblur event. For that I wrote simple JavaScript program see here http://jsfiddle.net/wHgH5/29/.
6. I wanted to create jquery plugin so I can use in future easily with more friendly code.
7. On "return this each function" you can see I wrote keypress and blur function for that specific reason.

Problems which I am facing:

1. Firstly the blur event is not working so I can't trigger beforeBlurAction, afterBlurAction, onComplete functions and not to mention all the functionality in triggerBlurAction will not work.
2. Secondly even on keypress event it's assuming all "numberTextBox" input elements are same and doesn't apply separately. To understand it run the code snippet there are two input box with same classes, now type/press from keyboard "2.1.1" it will only allow "2.1" in that input box but on the second one it won't allow decimal. but if you empty first input box and it will allow writing single decimal on the second input box. **I want to do it separately**.

Check here https://jsfiddle.net/mzhe2rde/

```js
//JQuery Custom Plugin inputNumericTextBox
(function($) {
  jQuery.fn.inputNumericTextBox = function(options) {

    var defaults = {
      negativeAllow: true,
      decimalAllow: true,
      decimalError: false,
      negativeSignError: false,
      beforeKeypressAction: function() {},
      afterKeypressAction: function() {},
      beforeBlurAction: function() {},
      afterBlurAction: function() {},
      onError: function() {},
      onComplete: function() {},
    };

    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    return this.each(function(i, element) {
      $(document).on('keypress', element, function(e) {
        triggerKeypressAction(e, element)
      });
      $(document).on('blur', element, function(e) {
        alert(); //for testing but it's now working
        triggerBlurAction(e, element)
      });
    });

    function triggerKeypressAction(evt, element) {
      settings.beforeKeypressAction.call(element, settings);

      var regex;
      var theEvent = evt || window.event;
      var key = String.fromCharCode(theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which);
      if (/\./.test(key) && /\./.test($(element).val())) {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        if (theEvent.preventDefault) {
          theEvent.preventDefault();
        }
        settings.decimalError = true;
        settings.onError.call(element, settings);
        return false;
      }

      /** Any idea on how to allow only one negative sign at the beginning?
         write regex code here **/

      if (settings.decimalAllow) {
        regex = (settings.negativeAllow) ? /[0-9]|\-|\./ : /[0-9]|\./;
      } else {
        regex = (settings.negativeAllow) ? /[0-9]|\-/ : /[0-9]/;
      }
      if (!regex.test(key)) {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
      }

      settings.afterKeypressAction.call(element, settings);
    }

    function triggerBlurAction(evt, element) {
      settings.beforeBlurAction.call(element, settings);

      var inputValue = $(element).val(),
        parsedValue = (settings.decimalAllow) ? parseFloat(inputValue) : parseInt(inputValue, 10);
      if (isNaN(parsedValue)) {
        $(element).val('');
      } else if (settings.negativeAllow) {
        $(element).val(parsedValue);
      } else {
        $(element).val(Math.abs(parsedValue));
      }

      settings.afterBlurAction.call(element, settings);
      settings.onComplete.call(element, settings);
    }

  };
})(jQuery);

$(".numberTextBox").inputNumericTextBox({
  negativeAllow: true,
  decimalAllow: true,
  beforeKeypressAction: function(e) {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(e);
    console.log('before key');
  },
  afterKeypressAction: function(e) {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(e);
    console.log('after key');
  },
  beforeBlurAction: function(e) {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(e);
    console.log('before blur');
  },
  afterBlurAction: function(e) {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(e);
    console.log('after blur');
  },
  onError: function(e) {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(e);
    console.log('on error');
    if (e.decimalError) {
      alert('More than one decimal number is not allowed');
    } else if (e.negativeSignError) {
      alert('More than one negative sign is not allowed.\n You can only use negative at the start');
    }
  },
  onComplete: function(e) {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(e);
    console.log('on complete');
  },

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <input id="firstbox" type="text" class="numberTextBox" />
  <input id="secondbox" type="text" class="numberTextBox" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I should try myself. what I did is put all the content of the plugin to another private function. and call the function in a loop to initialize every element separately. that way I achieved my goal and all events are working properly. and few more to support single negative sign. now it's proper input number textbox.

check it out here https://jsfiddle.net/mzhe2rde/6/

```js
//JQuery Custom Plugin inputNumericTextBox
(function($) {
    "use strict";

    var inputNumericTextBox = function(element, options) {
        var previous_value_set = false;
        var previous_value = '';
        var defaults = {
            negativeAllow: true,
            decimalAllow: true,
            decimalError: false,
            startNegativeSignError: false,
            multipleNegativeSignError: false,
            beforeKeypressAction: function() {},
            afterKeypressAction: function() {},
            beforeKeyupAction: function() {},
            afterKeyupAction: function() {},
            beforeBlurAction: function() {},
            afterBlurAction: function() {},
            onError: function() {},
            onInitializationComplete: function() {},
        };

        var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        $(element).on('keypress', function(e) {
            //console.log("keypress");
            triggerKeypressAction(e, element);
        });
        $(element).on('keyup', function(e) {
            //console.log("keyup");
            triggerKeyupAction(e, element);
        });
        $(element).on('blur', function(e) {
            //console.log("blur");
            triggerBlurAction(e, element);
        });

        settings.onInitializationComplete.call(element, settings);

        function triggerKeypressAction(evt, element) {
            settings.beforeKeypressAction.call(element, settings);

            var regex;
            var theEvent = evt || window.event;
            var key = String.fromCharCode(theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which);
            if (/\./.test(key) && /\./.test($(element).val())) {
                theEvent.returnValue = false;
                if (theEvent.preventDefault) {
                    theEvent.preventDefault();
                }
                settings.decimalError = true;
                settings.onError.call(element, settings);
                settings.afterKeypressAction.call(element, settings);
                settings.decimalError = false;
                return false;
            }

            if (/-/.test(key) && /-/.test($(element).val())) {
                theEvent.returnValue = false;
                if (theEvent.preventDefault) {
                    theEvent.preventDefault();
                }
                settings.multipleNegativeSignError = true;
                settings.onError.call(element, settings);
                settings.afterKeypressAction.call(element, settings);
                settings.multipleNegativeSignError = false;
                return false;
            }

            if (/-/.test(key)) {
                previous_value_set = true;
                previous_value = $(element).val();
            }

            if (settings.decimalAllow) {
                regex = (settings.negativeAllow) ? /[0-9]|-|\./ : /[0-9]|\./;
            } else {
                regex = (settings.negativeAllow) ? /[0-9]|-/ : /[0-9]/;
            }
            if (!regex.test(key)) {
                theEvent.returnValue = false;
                if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
            }
            settings.afterKeypressAction.call(element, settings);
        }

        function triggerKeyupAction(evt, element) {
            settings.beforeKeyupAction.call(element, settings);

            if (settings.negativeAllow && previous_value_set) {
                if (!(/^-.*/.test($(element).val()))) {
                    $(element).val(previous_value);
                    settings.startNegativeSignError = true;
                    settings.onError.call(element, settings);
                    settings.startNegativeSignError = false;
                }
            }
            previous_value_set = false;
            previous_value = '';

            settings.afterKeyupAction.call(element, settings);
        }

        function triggerBlurAction(evt, element) {
            settings.beforeBlurAction.call(element, settings);

            var inputValue = $(element).val(),
                parsedValue = (settings.decimalAllow) ? parseFloat(inputValue) : parseInt(inputValue, 10);
            if (isNaN(parsedValue)) {
                $(element).val('');
            } else if (settings.negativeAllow) {
                $(element).val(parsedValue);
            } else {
                $(element).val(Math.abs(parsedValue));
            }

            settings.afterBlurAction.call(element, settings);
        }
        return;
    };

    if (!jQuery.fn.inputNumericTextBox) {
        jQuery.fn.inputNumericTextBox = function(options) {
            return this.each(function() {
                inputNumericTextBox(this, options);
                return this;
            });
        };
    }

})(jQuery);

$(".numberTextBox").inputNumericTextBox({
    negativeAllow: true,
    decimalAllow: true,
    beforeKeypressAction: function(e) {
        //console.log(this);
        //console.log(e);
        //console.log('before keypress');
    },
    afterKeypressAction: function(e) {
        //console.log(this);
        //onsole.log(e);
        //console.log('after keypress');
    },
    beforeKeyupAction: function(e) {
        //console.log(this);
        //onsole.log(e);
        //console.log('before keyup');
    },
    afterKeyupAction: function(e) {
        //console.log(this);
        //onsole.log(e);
        //console.log('after keyup');
    },
    beforeBlurAction: function(e) {
        //console.log(this);
        //console.log(e);
        //console.log('before blur');
    },
    afterBlurAction: function(e) {
        //console.log(this);
        //console.log(e);
        //console.log('after blur');
    },
    onError: function(e) {
        //console.log(this);
        //console.log(e);
        //console.log('on error');
        if (e.decimalError) {
            alert('More than one decimal number is not allowed');
        } else if (e.multipleNegativeSignError) {
            alert('More than one negative sign is not allowed.');
        } else if (e.startNegativeSignError) {
            alert('You can only use one negative sign at the start');
        }
    },
    onInitializationComplete: function(e) {
        //console.log(this);
        //console.log(e);
        //console.log('on complete');
    },

});

/* Last initialization settings will take the precedence but events will trigger on all initialization
 * You shouldn't initialize more than one on a single element because it will create more object and it will take some memory to store it.
 * It's their to support large environment */

/* This is an example of last initialization or initialization more than one */

/*  
$(".numberTextBox").inputNumericTextBox();
var n = $(".numberTextBox").inputNumericTextBox({
    negativeAllow: false,
    decimalAllow: true
});
console.log(n);*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <input type="text" class="numberTextBox" />
    <input type="text" class="numberTextBox" />
</body>
```